# Checking the number of confirmed blocks for a transaction?

Tags: ethereum, go-ethereum

How does one check the number of "block confirmations" for a given transaction?

I tried checking the transaction hash in block heights of +1, +2, etc. but they don't contain the transaction ID.

Would I instead need to wait for future blocks to be mined, and the transaction status to still be considered valid? the [Receipt.Status](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum@v1.10.16/core/types#Receipt).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After lots of research, I can say that it is the number of blocks that have been mined after the block your transaction was included in, and your transaction is still considered valid. So to check block confirmations, you would check whether the transaction is still valid, and see how many more blocks above the transaction block height have been mined.

> Therefore, if your transaction has 13 block confirmations (see above graphic), then there have been 12 blocks mined since the block was mined that included your transaction.

[https://jaredstauffer.medium.com/what-is-a-block-confirmation-on-ethereum-e27d29ca8c01#:~:text=A%20block%20confirmation%20is%20simply,mined%20that%20included%20your%20transaction](https://jaredstauffer.medium.com/what-is-a-block-confirmation-on-ethereum-e27d29ca8c01#:%7E:text=A%20block%20confirmation%20is%20simply,mined%20that%20included%20your%20transaction).